# Simple speed up of C++ OpenMP kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I have never worked with OpenMP or optimization of C++, so all help is welcome.  I'm probably doing some very stupid things that slow down the process drastically. It doesn't need to be the fastest, but I think some easy tricks will significantly speed it up. Anyone? Thanks a lot!

This function calculates the standard deviation of a patch, given a kernel size and greyscale OpenCV image. The middle pixel of the patch is kept if it is below the given threshold, else it is rejected. This is done for each pixel except the border.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utils.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat low_pass_filter(Mat img, int threshold, int kernelSize)
{
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);
    Mat output = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
    unsigned char *output_ptr = (unsigned char*)(output.data);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = (kernelSize - 1) / 2; i < img.rows - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; i++){
        for (int j = (kernelSize - 1) / 2; j < img.cols - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; j++){
            double sum, m, accum, stdev;
            vector<double> v;
            // Kernel Patch
            for (int kx = i - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; kx <= i + (kernelSize - 1) / 2; kx++){
                for (int ky = j - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; ky <= j + (kernelSize - 1) / 2; ky++){
                    v.push_back((double)input[img.step * kx + ky]);//.at<uchar>(kx, ky));
                }
            }
            sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.0);
            m = sum / v.size();

            accum = 0.0;
            std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](const double d) {
                accum += (d - m) * (d - m);
            });

            stdev = sqrt(accum / (v.size() - 1));
            if (stdev < threshold){
                output_ptr[img.step * i + j] = input[img.step * i + j];
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're solving? Seems like this belongs to codereview stackexchange, no?

Comment: Would like to have some speed-up. Not familiar with codereview, did I place it at the wrong place?

Comment: Is the OMP version faster than the non-OMP version?

Comment: @PieterBosma it would seem so. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for asking help to improve your code.  These questions are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Not OMP related, preallocate `vector<double> v`. i.e. `v.reserve(kernelSize*kernelSize);` before the two inner-most loops.

Comment: Oke, thank you anyway

Comment: Quadruple nested `for` loops are not going to be fast....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Moved to code review:
[Link to the code review][1]


  [1]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92988/simple-speed-up-of-c-openmp-kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector v is not required.  Instead of adding items to it, maintain accumulators of `d` and `d*d`, and then use [variance = E(v²) / E(v)²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) so that your inner code becomes:

```
        double sum = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;
        int n = kernelSize * kernelSize;
        // Kernel Patch
        for (int kx = ...) {
            for (int ky = ...) {
                sum += d;
                sum2 += d*d;
            }
        }

        double mean = sum/n;
        double stddev = sqrt(sum2/n - mean*mean);
        if (stddev < threshold) {
            ...;
        }
```

After that, consider that the sum of elements centred around (x+1,y) can be found from the result for (x,y) simply by subtracting all the elements in the previous left-hand column, and adding all the elements in the new right-hand column.  An analogous operation works vertically.

Also, check your compiler options - are you auto-vectorizing loops, and using SIMD instructions (if available)?

Comment: Can you please explain in code?
if I remove: vector<double> v; v is undefined

Comment: "After that, consider that the sum of elements centred around (x+1,y) can be found from the result for (x,y) simply by subtracting all the elements in the previous left-hand column, and adding all the elements in the new right-hand column. An analogous operation works vertically."

I have thought about this before posting. Too much for now I think

Comment: @Pieter - I've updated my answer with approximate code to explain myself better.

Comment: I think you mean that:
    double d = (double)input[img.step * kx + ky])

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a lot lot faster!